# Need help in framing mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to check in a table table1 number of records with sno = 5.

All I need is a boolean true or false.

How to do it?

I can do

```
select count(*) from table1 where sno = 5
```

and then check return value is equal to 5 or not.

I'm want something like this:

```
select 1 (else 0) where (select count(*) from table1 ) = 5;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select IF(count(*)=5, 1, 0) as has_5_items from table1 where sno = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(id)
WHEN 5 THEN "true"
ELSE "false"
END
AS cn_val
FROM table where sno = 5
```

Comment: Yes your answer is what I was looking for. But can I use:  SELECT count(*) = 5 from table1 which simply returns 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

You want to check whether there are exactly 5 records in the table which match the criterion `sno = 5`? You can do this with a statement like this:

```
select (select count(*) from table1 WHERE sno = 5) = 5
```

but I wouldn't bother with that kind of wrapping. Just run this SQL:

```
select count(*) from table1 WHERE sno = 5
```

and then check in your code whether the result is equal to 5 or not.

Your question is confusing because the value 5 is used in two places: the value of the sno column you want to match, and the number of matching records you want to find.

Comment: how about : SELECT count(*) <> 5 from table1

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GROUP BY...HAVING` query.

```
SELECT sno, COUNT(sno) AS sno_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY sno
HAVING COUNT(sno) = 5 
AND sno = 5
```

By leaving out the final `AND sno = 5` you can get all the values for `sno` which have exactly 5 records.